# VueJS $els command returns null

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created the following structure:

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 mapContainer">
                <div class="GISMap" v-el:map></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 incidentContainer">
                <div class="incidentForm">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my JS i want to get an element from the DOM:

```
  init: function() {
     initGISMap(this.$els.map);
  }
```

But the `this.$els.map` does not return a value. Therefore googlemaps cannot initialize. I placed the `v-el:map` attribute into my div GISMap. Therefore I think it should be found. Did I miss something?

Comment: you should run that in the ready() hook. before that, the component won't be inserted into the DOM. Also, there is no init() hook in Vue to my knowledge. http://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram